# When you have two teeth implantation

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Imagine a dentist implants a tooth into your gum. You would probably say: "I got a tooth implant. But what do you say when you get two teeth implantations?

Does the following sentences sound idiomatic? If not what would a native speaker would say instead:

> - I implanted two teeth.
> - I got two teeth implantations.
> - I had two teeth implantations.

P.S. "[Implantation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/implantation)" is marked as an incorrect word by the forum spell-checking system. But as you see in the link, it is defined as a countable or an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AmE they're called **implants** or **tooth-implants|tooth implants**.

> I got a tooth implant.
>
> I got two teeth implanted.
>
> I got two tooth-implants.

The attributive **tooth** (*tooth-implant*) doesn't change in number.  It remains singular.

We wouldn't say

> The spa gift certificate was for two backs<sup>ungrammatical</sup> massages.